# Twitter public dataset

Tags: twitter, datasource

I am going to write an small application which requires twitter data. Can some one give me a good data source for twitter data. It would be great if data is large as the application is going to run a data mining algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the APIs from Twitter?  You can build a data set with the [Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) or just iterate through a dictionary and use the [Search API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search)

Comment: Dont you think it will take some effort. As its a small application It would be great if I have to just spend my efforts of developing application and not getting data. But yes if there is no data available and dont have any other option then your idea would work.

Answer (score 0):

This short [tutorial](http://poli.bonzahost.net/2009/11/03/twitter-search/) shows how to get and filter data using Twitter API. You set language, keyword and other parameters.

If you need to integrate a simple widget in your web pages you can get JavaScript source at twitter web site.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Twitter Streaming API Sample resource to collect data from Twitter. The Search API is not intended for automated search.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [jetwick](https://github.com/karussell/Jetwick) (open source)

At the moment we have 10 mio tweets per week, but you can improve that with more servers ;)

Comment: fixed the link. you now have to set it up on your own

Answer (score -1):

You can get a twitter dataset from http://dmml.asu.edu/datasets/

Comment: Seems the site is password protected now.

Comment: Same for me. The site is not reachable for the public any more

Comment: why would you suggest a password protected site